# Easily creating a bash script in python

Tags: python, bash

I'm looking to write some tests that will create and execute a bash script. Bash itself has a nice way to do this:

```
 % cat > run.sh << EOF
 > echo "I ran this"
 > EOF
 % . run.sh
 I ran this
```

In Python I can do this:

```
 with open ('run.sh', 'w') as rsh:
    rsh.write('echo "I ran this"\n')
 -- etc ---
```

This is fine for a short script in Python, but I'm wondering if there is some technique I don't know about that let's me do something like what I can do in bash.

Comment: Triple quoted string literal?

Comment: D'oh!

I forgot about that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

with open ('run.sh', 'w') as rsh:
    rsh.write('''\
#! /bin/bash
echo "I ran this"
echo "more lines"
''')
```

Comment: Thanks. I had forgotten about this.

Comment: Mostly a style issue, but I wouldn't bother with the backslash. The `bash` script won't care about an empty line at the start of the script.

Comment: @chepner the first line might be the shebang and then it matters

Comment: I'd still put the shebang on the first line to avoid the backslash, as it isn't (semantically) relevant to the rest of the content. (Actually, I'd probably not put a shebang at all, if I had any control over the test runner, because it would be running the commands with an explicit shell rather than assuming the test scripts are executable.)

Comment: That was my edit too. @chepner.  Not sure why it was rejected.

Comment: Starting multiline strings with `'''\ ` is idiomatic. I can't see why there would be a style issue with it

Comment: Presumably you also want to make the script executable:

`f = Path('run_mlm_loop.sh')
f.chmod(f.stat().st_mode | stat.S_IEXEC)`

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use writelines here:

```
with open ('run.sh', 'w') as rsh:
    rsh.writelines('echo "I ran this"\n')
```